# How to safely wrap optional values in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this piece of code :

```
     var array: [Int]? = []

 array = data.characters.split(){$0 == ","}.map{
        (Int(String.init($0).
stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())))!}
```

which reads the data from the file and if there are `Int`s separated by a single comma, it will convert them into array of `Int`. My question is how do I safely wrap it so I dont get this error : `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` ?

Comment: Remove the `!` and use `flatMap` instead of `map`.

Comment: @EricD thank you Eric, that worked!